# Let $f(x)$ be an increasing function defined on $(0,\infty)$ if $f(2a^2+a+1)>f(3a^2-4a+1)$ then no. of possible integers in the range of a is :

Tags: calculus

$f(x)>0$ but how do I reduce the latter factorised as 
$f(2a^2+a+1) - f((3a-1)(a-1)) \gt 0$
Since the entire range will be positive, the minima value must be $\gt 0$ how do we resolve it to that 
Or any other possible approach

We could do f-inverse on both sides in the question itself but we don't
 know the nature of f-inverse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is 3.

If $f$ is increasing then $f(x) > f(y)$ implies $x > y$.
So you have $2a^2 + a + 1 > 3a^2 - 4a + 1$, which simplifies to $a < 5$. 
Moreover , $3a^2 - 4a + 1>0$ , So $a\in (-\infty,1/3)\cup (1,\infty)$.
Satisfying both the equations , only integers in the range are:- $2,3,4$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 3.

If $f$ is increasing then $f(x) > f(y)$ implies $x > y$.
So you have $2a^2 + a + 1 > 3a^2 - 4a + 1$, which simplifies to $a < 5$. 
Moreover , $3a^2 - 4a + 1>0$ , So $a∈(-∞,1/3)U(1,∞)$
Satisfying both the equations , only integers in the range are:- $2,3,4$.